# Spring Dependency Injection stopped working

Tags: java, spring, dependencies, inversion-of-control, code-injection

I'm working with a team of 10+ Java developers on a web application. It's a big project (2 years old) and we've come accross an issue since last night: some beans (2 beans) cause a NullPointerException when used (as if the IoC doesn't work anymore).

The thing is, everything was working fine two days ago, and I've read every single commit during these two days, but there was no change in the Spring Confugration files.

I know that sometimes if you dynamically inject a bean through Spring and instanciate it through the new operand, it gives a NPE but there is no sign of this on the project.

All the developers do not have this problem on their local machines, but on the CI servers, it works fine for a while then it stops until we restart the machine (not the server). Does anyone has an idea how to deal with this problem? The server startup doesn't show any errors at all.

**UPDATE:**

- The server context initialization shows absolutely no errors (nor warnings), and ends with a success message.
- I've checked all calls to the bean setters: none used.
- The beans are picked up through a configuration file, no @Autowired.
- I've actually searched the whole project for the new operand, took me almost two hours to check each one, but there was no bean instancied with a new operand.

Comment: Somewhere some piece of code is setting your member as null ("It works fine for a while and then stops."). Are you sure you are not calling a setX() anywhere from within your code?

Comment: can you add a bit detail on this? stacktraces code snippets or logs if you can turn on debug logging on spring

Comment: increase log level and show us some relevant log and spring configuration file. check for circular dependency.

Comment: If these beans are singletons  then the spring will fail fast during the context initialization. Maybe it's connected with the server state. How are these bean picked up? Is is context/component scan, is it a bean configuration file. Anyway I think that duffymo and TJ are right - likely one of 10+ developers does something like setSomeBeanReference(new ...) P.S. Can you how are these beans autowired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to a conflict between JavaMelody and Spring AOP. To solve it we had to disable JavaMelody for a while, until we know the root of the problem.

**From JavaMelody FAQ (for more information)**

*If ever, there is a conflict in your application between the all-in-one monitoring-spring.xml and AOP or @Autowired, then you can use the monitoring-spring-datasource.xml file, instead of monitoring-spring.xml. This file contains only the datasource post-processor and an example of SpringDataSourceFactoryBean.*

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that someone called "new" to create a bean, which means it's no longer under the control of the Spring bean factory, but somehow it depends on DI.  It's even more likely if you're using annotations to wire in resources.

You said it yourself: It's been working fine for years.  Spring didn't fail suddenly.  It's more likely that one of those 10+ Java developers is new or doesn't understand Spring as well as they think they do.